# Is there any way to render freshservice app on portal pages (Requesters view)

Tags: javascript, ajax, freshdesk

My Requirement is 
1. User will type subject.
2. On the basis of subject, I want to call third party rest API (Currently being blocked by CORS. even the jsonp request is also not working)
3. I want to set some field values on form according to the response

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot render an Freshservice app from the customer's view (User/Employee/Requester) as of now. Instead you can create Freshservice app on Agent portal where tickets are managed.

1. [Create](https://developers.freshservice.com/docs/overview/) a serverless app.
2. On `onTicketCreate` product event you can write in your logic in `server.js`:

`exports = {
    events: [{
        event: "onTicketCreate",
        callback: "onTicketCreateCallback"
    }],
    onTicketCreateCallback: function(payload) {
        console.log("Logging arguments from onTicketCreate event: " + JSON.stringify(payload));
        // 1.Implement the logic with the help of payload's ticket subject that you are looking for.
        // 2. To shoot bypass CORS use platform's request API - https://developers.freshservice.com/docs/request-api/
        // 3. Update the Fields using - https://api.freshservice.com/v2/#view_a_change
    }
}`

3. See [this reference](https://api.freshservice.com/v2/#change_attributes) for making changes to agent facing field values.

In simple terms this process results to fill in fields as per your use case. Only difference is, it happens on creating a ticket but not while filling up the requester facing form.